# Android 3.0: Why can I not choose a mobile phone skin for >=Android3.0?

Tags: android, skin

I would like to test my application on Android3.0 with a HVGA, QVGA or any mobile phone skin, but my installation only offers me one WXGA skin which then finally shows me a tablet screen. Neither is my application made for tablets nor is my computer strong enough to make use of such a big VM screen.

What can I do, to get a normal mobile phone screen for my Android VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know Android 3.0 is the tablet OS, Android 2.3.3 is the Phone OS, it might be 2.3.4 as the newest version now. So start a VM with 2.3 rather than 3.0.

Edit: 2.3 is Gingerbread for phones, 3.0 is Honeycomb for tablets. 4.0 is targetted for Q4 this year and is designed for both from what I can tell.

Comment: Okay, but there is some functionality in the tutorial that expects API Level 11, which is 3.0. How to solve this?

Comment: What tutorial is it and what functionality is it expecting?

Comment: I just copied all the files into a Android2.1 project and watched eclipse do its error finding thing. Just some string changes and one PipeDataWriter Interface that I probably don't need for that tutorial. The example is the Notepad on developers.android.com. The Exercise1 Text and the Source Code seem to be out of sync anyway.

Comment: I count it as solved now and later on will try to work around the missing interface if it should be needed. Thanks.